# Horizontal and Vertical Projection on Binary image for text line extraction using Emgu

Tags: emgucv

I'm using tesseract and Emgu to develop OCR project for myanmar language. After binarization process, i want to segment each text line from the binary image using vertical and horizontal projection. Problem is I don't know how to do that using Emgu. Please help me with code example. thank you all.